# Is it possible to create an SFTP drop box?

Tags: linux, windows, python, sftp, dropbox

I have a Windows server with folders accessible via SFTP (server is running OpenSSH). `scp` is blocked. I would like to copy files from a Linux server to the Windows server. SFTP seems like a good option. Ideally I'd like something similar to an FTP drop box, so that the Linux box could just copy files directly over to the Windows box.

I'm also open to any solutions to this that would allow me to copy the files while offering the least amount of hassle.

The language I'd be using on the Linux box is python; not sure if that factors in or not.

Comment: ntfs and samba are also out, btw. Although the two servers are on the same local network now, the Linux server may not always be and the firewall rules on the local network are pretty strict (dure to org. policy) and I'm not sure I could get around them, so it would all have to take place through common ports like 80, 443, 22, etc.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by FTP drop box.  SCP runs on port 22 same as SFTP and SSH so if it's not available you just need to change your OpenSSH settings.

Comment: FTP drop boxes were common maybe in the earlier days of the Internet (if you are willing to accept the mid-to-late 90s as "early" -- it was certainly early for me!). Basically you could add files but not read or modify. It was an easy way for anonymous users to get their files on a server. The idea of an SFTP drop box appealed to me because it meant I could get a file onto the server without having to deal with usernames and passwords. As it happened, I used paramiko along with a client-side certificate for SSL authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use python, try this. [sftp in python using paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432385/sftp-in-python-platform-independent)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try [SSHFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) to mount the windows servers' folders on your linux box.

I haven't tried it myself, but there are some articles out there for tunneling samba over SSH.

A VPN may be useful if you are able to set one up between the two boxes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Running into some problems getting SSHFS installed but that's another issue; might just ignore it altogether until the server move (whenever that happens).

Answer (score 0):

If you say that SFTP is enabled, but SCP is blocked: It seems that SFTP on that machine won't work altogether.

You could setup OpenVPN on that Windows server and use OpenVPN from linux over the network to connect to it. Then use samba to copy it. This will give you also the advantage to browse the .org network from anywhere in the world.

Or you could install a linux virtual machine on the server with the SSH port NAT-ed to it and has the server drives mounted through samba.

Comment: I've been using it for years; SFTP can work on a server with SCP disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following.

Download a client called BitVise Tunnlier, (I don't work for them and I'm not affiliated in anyway shape or form!), and then log into the windows box, with appropriate credentials, then open up an SFTP window.

If this works, then SCP will work - If it doesn't work, then you need to fix the SSH daemon on your windows box :)

I've never encountered an SSH daemon, that I couldn't SFTP into, or use SCP to copy files. If the SSH protocol is active, the SCP and SFTP are both available to you.